# Fan control of my Samsung Chronos 7

Tags: release-freya

I have recently switched from Windows 8.1 to Elementary OS on my Samsung Chronos NP700Z5A. I have followed all the instructions that I found and the OS works quite well. I have installed the Samsung tools, which enables the function keys. IT allows changing the fan's working modes on 3 levels. The only problem that is that the fan does work most of the time even in the silent mode.

I encountered this problem when I switched from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 until I could find the matched version of Samsung tools. It looks that the Ubuntu software has not been set properly. It considerably reduces the battery life.

Can anyone suggest me any solution?

Best Mehran

Answer (score 1):

A lot of laptop tools which exist on Windows doesn't exist on Linux systems. You can try something universal like [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/142249)